# Divisor Function of Highly Composite Numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

It is known that
$$
\exp\left\{k(1/1.71\cdots+o(1))\right\} < H(k) < \exp\left\{k(1/1.13862\cdots+o(1))\right\},
$$
where $H(k)$ is the $k^{th}$ [highly composite number.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number)

**Question:** Does the number of divisors of the highly composite numbers $d(H(k))$ achieve the growth rate given by
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup \frac{\log d(n)}{\frac{ \log n}{\log \log n}}=\log 2?
$$
To be more precise let $n_k=H(k).$ Does
$$
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sup \frac{\log d(n_k)}{\frac{ \log n_k}{\log \log n_k}}=\log 2?
$$

Comment: highly composite number?

Comment: @WlodAA, sorry I don't understand your comment

Comment: @WlodAA see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number

Comment: In brief: "A highly composite number is a positive integer with more divisors than any smaller positive integer has."

Comment: @SungjinKim, MO q's are meant for the entire MO audience, not for narrow specialists only. Thus an MO question should provide the key definition or else many MO participants will ignore the question which would be unfortunate for them. Also, some non-specialists still have a chance to say something interesting about the Question. Instead of a zillion of MO participants running to Wikipedia, the author of the Q. should simply include the definition to make the text more self-contained.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you. Thus, this sequence starts with 1, and goes on like this: 1 2 4 6 12 24 36..., right? – Wlod AA 19

Comment: @WlodAA yes. OEIS A002182.

Comment: Thank you. Looks exciting. :)

Comment: The wikipedia link has a link to Erdos paper. The Lemma 1 of that paper implies that the limsup in your question is positive.

Comment: @SungjinKim, can you elaborate? Write as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying Lemma 1 from Erdos [paper](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1944-04.pdf), we are able to obtain
$$
\limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log d(n_k)}{\frac{ \log n_k}{\log \log n_k}}\geq \frac16\log 2.
$$
Here's the proof. Let $N$ be a highly composite number other than 4, 36, we have the prime factorization of $N$ as
$$
N=2^{a_2}3^{a_3}\cdots p^{a_p}, \ \ a_2\geq \cdots\geq a_p=1.
$$
Then 
$$
d(N)=(a_2+1)(a_3+1)\cdots(a_p+1) \geq 2^{\pi(p)}
$$
Taking logarithms, 
$$
\log d(N)\geq \pi(p) \log 2. 
$$
Lemma 1 from Erdos paper states $p>c\log N$ for some positive $c$. But, by following his argument there, we can see that $c$ can be taken as $1/6-\epsilon$. (see Proof of Lemma 1)

Then it follows that 
$$
\log d(N) \geq (1/6-\epsilon)\frac{\log N \log 2}{\log \log N}.
$$
Therefore, we have the result.

**Remark**

We actually have 
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log d(n_k)}{\frac{\log n_k}{\log\log n_k}} = \log 2. 
$$
The proof is given in this [66 page paper](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram15.pdf) by Ramanujan. 
More specifically, see section 32 to 39.

Comment: It seems that the final Remark is a complete answer to the question in the OP, and the rest is probably best deleted.

Comment: @GregMartin It might make sense to have it after the Remark, but it seems relevant for giving a quick and easy bound that is almost as good.

Comment: @GregMartin, Thanks for your comment. I actually find the simple argument quite nice, so I'll accept the answer as it is.